# Multi condition in ng-class Angular

Tags: angularjs

here is my conditions how can i mix them ?

```
ng-class="{'highlight': ((obj.Count == 1 && setActionType != 1 && setActionType != 20 ) || (setActionType == 1 || setActionType == 20)) && (setActionType != 60 && setActionType != -1 && setActionType != 50) ? smartAlertNewBranch($index) : false}"
```

and i want to add this  condition : `[obj.BackgroundColor,obj.ColumnColor]`

what's the syntax ?
Thanks

Comment: [obj.BackgroundColor,obj.ColumnColor] ??  what this suppose to mean ?

Comment: That is way too much expression-logic for the mockup code, I highly recommend to put that into a controller, so your markup stays readable

Comment: @Anik i got the color class with this condition

Comment: yes i know , btw is this possible to add the second condition to first condition